# Python suds - method not defined in service

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm attempting to use `suds` to connect to a `KnowledgeTree` web service on my local network.  I can create the client and retrieve the service information, but calling the `login` method listed there produces `suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'method "login" not defined in service'`.

*(Note: I had to use ImportDoctor to resolve a namespace issue when creating the client.  I don't know if the current problem could be related.)*

Is there a problem with the way I'm setting up the client or sending the command, or is the problem server-side?  I can alter the code on the server that generates the WSDL if necessary, but I don't know what needs to be corrected at this point.

Setting up the client:

```
import logging
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
import getpass

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
url='http://192.168.1.213/knowledgetree/ktwebservice/webservice.php?wsdl'
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('urn:KnowledgeTree')
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(url, doctor=d)

print(client)
response = client.service.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass(), '192.168.1.42')
```

Results of `print(client)`:

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( KnowledgeTreeService ) tns="urn:KnowledgeTree"
   Prefixes (2)
      ns0 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      ns1 = "urn:KnowledgeTree"
   Ports (1):
      (KnowledgeTreePort)
         Methods (60):
            add_base64_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string title, xs:string filename, xs:string documentype, xs:string base64, )
            add_base64_document_with_metadata(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string title, xs:string filename, xs:string documentype, xs:string base64, kt_metadata_fieldsets metadata, kt_sysdata sysdata, )
            add_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string title, xs:string filename, xs:string documentype, xs:string tempfilename, )
            add_document_with_metadata(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string title, xs:string filename, xs:string documentype, xs:string tempfilename, kt_metadata_fieldsets metadata, kt_sysdata sysdata, )
            add_folder(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string folder_name, )
            add_small_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string title, xs:string filename, xs:string documentype, xs:string base64, )
            anonymous_login(xs:string ip, )
            change_document_owner(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string username, xs:string reason, )
            change_document_type(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string documenttype, )
            checkin_base64_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string filename, xs:string reason, xs:string base64, xs:boolean major_update, )
            checkin_base64_document_with_metadata(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string filename, xs:string reason, xs:string base64, xs:boolean major_update, kt_metadata_fieldsets metadata, kt_sysdata sysdata, )
            checkin_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string filename, xs:string reason, xs:string tempfilename, xs:boolean major_update, )
            checkin_document_with_metadata(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string filename, xs:string reason, xs:string tempfilename, xs:boolean major_update, kt_metadata_fieldsets metadata, kt_sysdata sysdata, )
            checkin_small_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string filename, xs:string reason, xs:string base64, xs:boolean major_update, )
            checkout_base64_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string reason, xs:boolean download, )
            checkout_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string reason, xs:boolean download, )
            checkout_small_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string reason, xs:boolean download, )
            copy_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string reason, xs:string options, )
            copy_folder(xs:string session_id, xs:int source_id, xs:int target_id, xs:string reason, )
            create_folder(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string folder_name, )
            delete_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string reason, )
            delete_document_workflow(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            delete_folder(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string reason, )
            download_base64_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            download_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            download_small_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            get_client_policies(xs:string session_id, xs:string client, )
            get_document_detail(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string detail, )
            get_document_detail_by_filename(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string filename, xs:string detail, )
            get_document_detail_by_name(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string document_name, xs:string what, xs:string detail, )
            get_document_detail_by_title(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string title, xs:string detail, )
            get_document_link_types(xs:string session_id, )
            get_document_links(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            get_document_metadata(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            get_document_transaction_history(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            get_document_type_metadata(xs:string session_id, xs:string document_type, )
            get_document_types(xs:string session_id, )
            get_document_version_history(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            get_document_workflow_state(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            get_document_workflow_transitions(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            get_documents_by_oem_no(xs:string session_id, xs:string oem_no, xs:string detail, )
            get_folder_contents(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:int depth, xs:string what, )
            get_folder_detail(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, )
            get_folder_detail_by_name(xs:string session_id, xs:string folder_name, )
            get_workflows(xs:string session_id, )
            link_documents(xs:string session_id, xs:int parent_document_id, xs:int child_document_id, xs:string type, )
            login(xs:string username, xs:string password, xs:string ip, )
            logout(xs:string session_id, )
            move_document(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string reason, xs:string options, )
            move_folder(xs:string session_id, xs:int source_id, xs:int target_id, xs:string reason, )
            perform_document_workflow_transition(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string transition, xs:string reason, )
            rename_document_filename(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string newfilename, )
            rename_document_title(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string newtitle, )
            rename_folder(xs:string session_id, xs:int folder_id, xs:string newname, )
            search(xs:string session_id, xs:string search, xs:string options, )
            start_document_workflow(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string workflow, )
            stop_document_workflow(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, )
            undo_document_checkout(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, xs:string reason, )
            unlink_documents(xs:string session_id, xs:int parent_document_id, xs:int child_document_id, )
            update_document_metadata(xs:string session_id, xs:int document_id, kt_metadata_fieldsets metadata, kt_sysdata sysdata, )
         Types (89):
            ns0:Array
            ns0:ENTITIES
            ns0:ENTITY
            ns0:ID
            ns0:IDREF
            ns0:IDREFS
            ns0:NCName
            ns0:NMTOKEN
            ns0:NMTOKENS
            ns0:NOTATION
            ns0:Name
            ns0:QName
            ns0:Struct
            ns0:anyURI
            ns0:arrayCoordinate
            ns0:base64
            ns0:base64Binary
            ns0:boolean
            ns0:byte
            ns0:date
            ns0:dateTime
            ns0:decimal
            ns0:double
            ns0:duration
            ns0:float
            ns0:gDay
            ns0:gMonth
            ns0:gMonthDay
            ns0:gYear
            ns0:gYearMonth
            ns0:hexBinary
            ns0:int
            ns0:integer
            kt_client_policies_array
            kt_client_policies_response
            kt_client_policy
            kt_document_collection
            kt_document_collection_response
            kt_document_detail
            kt_document_transaction_history
            kt_document_transaction_history_item
            kt_document_transaction_history_response
            kt_document_types_array
            kt_document_types_response
            kt_document_version_history
            kt_document_version_history_item
            kt_document_version_history_response
            kt_folder_collection
            kt_folder_collection_response
            kt_folder_contents
            kt_folder_detail
            kt_folder_item
            kt_folder_items
            kt_linked_document
            kt_linked_document_response
            kt_linked_documents
            kt_metadata_field
            kt_metadata_fields
            kt_metadata_fieldset
            kt_metadata_fieldsets
            kt_metadata_options
            kt_metadata_response
            kt_metadata_selection
            kt_metadata_selection_item
            kt_response
            kt_search_response
            kt_search_result_item
            kt_search_results
            kt_sysdata
            kt_sysdata_item
            kt_workflow_transitions
            kt_workflow_transitions_response
            kt_workflows_array
            kt_workflows_response
            ns0:language
            ns0:long
            ns0:negativeInteger
            ns0:nonNegativeInteger
            ns0:nonPositiveInteger
            ns0:normalizedString
            ns0:positiveInteger
            ns0:short
            ns0:string
            ns0:time
            ns0:token
            ns0:unsignedByte
            ns0:unsignedInt
            ns0:unsignedLong
            ns0:unsignedShort
```

Debug results of `client.service.login(username, password, address)`:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (http://192.168.1.213/knowledgetree/ktwebservice/webservice.php)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns1:login>
         <username xsi:type="ns2:string">*removed*</username>
         <password xsi:type="ns2:string">*removed*</password>
         <ip xsi:type="ns2:string">192.168.1.42</ip>
      </ns1:login>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': u'"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/#KTWebService#login"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns1:login>
         <username xsi:type="ns2:string">*removed*</username>
         <password xsi:type="ns2:string">*removed*</password>
         <ip xsi:type="ns2:string">192.168.1.42</ip>
      </ns1:login>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<SOAP-ENV:Envelope  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"

 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

<SOAP-ENV:Body>



<SOAP-ENV:Fault>

<faultcode xsi:type="xsd:QName">SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>

<faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">method &quot;login&quot; not defined in service</faultstring>

<faultactor xsi:type="xsd:anyURI"></faultactor>

<detail xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:anyType[6]" SOAP-ENC:offset="[0]">

<item>

<object xsi:nil="true"/></item>

<item>

<object xsi:nil="true"/></item>

<item>

<object>

<fault xsi:nil="true"/></object></item>

<item>

<object>

<fault xsi:nil="true"/></object></item>

<item>

<object>

<fault xsi:nil="true"/></object></item>

<item>

<object xsi:nil="true"/></item></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault>

</SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    response = client.service.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass(), '192.168.1.42')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 702, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
WebFault: Server raised fault: 'method "login" not defined in service'
```

Comment: I've made zero progress trying to figure this out.  If anyone else runs into the same problem, my advice is to save yourself the trouble and use REST instead.

Comment: I think that is solid advice. SOAP can be a huge pain when the WSDL does not properly reference the methods. REST, on the other hand, relies on you, the consumer, to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

I had lots of issues trying to use suds to connect to KT. Below is the module I ended up using.

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
from suds.plugin import Plugin

import urllib

class SessionProxy:
    """
    All methods (except login) wants sessionid as first argument
    This proxy adds that.
    """
    def __init__(self, service, session, baseurl):
        self.service = service
        self.session = session
        self.baseurl = baseurl

    def open(self, docid):
        u = self.download_document(docid)
        return urllib.urlopen(self.baseurl + u.message)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        a = getattr(self.service, attr)
        if callable(a):
            def _(*args):
                return a(self.session, *args)
            return _
        return a

class AdjustPrefixes(Plugin):
    def sending(self, ctx):
        ctx.envelope.refitPrefixes()

class AttrFixer(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, attrs):
        self.attrs = attrs

    def received(self, ctx):
        # ideally this should parse the xml and rewrite the dom..
        for fr, to in self.attrs:
            ctx.reply = ctx.reply.replace("<%s " % fr, "<%s " % to)
            ctx.reply = ctx.reply.replace("</%s" % fr, "</%s" % to)


def connect(baseurl, user, password):
    url = "%s/ktwebservice/webservice.php?wsdl" % baseurl

    imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
    doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)
    client = Client(url, plugins=[doctor,
                                  AdjustPrefixes(),
                                  AttrFixer([(a.replace("_",""), a) for a in ["checked_out_by", "modified_by"]])])
    srv = client.service
    r = srv.login(user,password,"127.0.0.1")
    if r.status_code != 0:
        raise RuntimeError, "failed to login"
    s = SessionProxy(srv, r.message, baseurl)
    return s
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can post an example of a working envelope?  Your code produces the same `suds.WebFault` for me, but this definitely seems like the right direction to go if I can figure out what exactly needs to be fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the soap interface in our KT installation at work is broken so can't test it now. Will get back when it is working again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ns1:login>
    <username xsi:type="ns2:string">*removed*</username>
    <password xsi:type="ns2:string">*removed*</password>
    <ip xsi:type="ns2:string">192.168.1.42</ip>
</ns1:login>
```

ns0:string is the correct one not ns2:string

Comment: I set up a MessagePlugin to alter these in the outgoing document, and it still raises the same exception.